# Room many to many relationships UNIQUE constraint failed when inserting into relational table

Tags: java, android, sql, relationship, android-room

I try to understand how to work with many to many relationships in room.

I created a junction:

```
    @Entity(primaryKeys = {"landing_id", "takeoff_id"})
    public class TakeoffLanding {
        public long takeoff_id;
        public long landing_id;
    }
```

I created a matching abstract method in the dao:

```
@Transaction
@Insert
abstract void insert(List<TakeoffLanding> takeoffLandings);
```

My takeoff and landing classes look like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "landing_table")
public class Landing {

   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   public long landing_id;
}
```

When trying to add to the database I get an error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint
> failed: TakeoffLanding.landing_id, TakeoffLanding.takeoff_id (code
> 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)

I probably don't fully understand the concepts behind this - but somehow I should be able to add more landings and more takeoffs with the same primary key? or do i need to have a primary key for each column (id-pair) in the junction as well?

Comment: these might help https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542

Comment: yeah i was reading that one. I still dont get how to insert the relationship into the database. Querying it is explained really well. And from using sql a bit before i get i got to add the relationship into an extra table. But somehow i am stuck here for  days. I think about just using plain sql querys instead of trying to use room for this.